# Jenkins instance is missing

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to create a quicklab on GCP to implement CI/CD with Jenkins on GKE, I created a **Multibranch Pipeline**. When I push the modified script  to git, Jenkins kicks off a build and fails with the following error:

> ```
>     Branch indexing
>      > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>     Setting origin to https://source.developers.google.com/p/qwiklabs-gcp-gcpd-502b5f86f641/r/default
>      > git config remote.origin.url https://source.developers.google.com/p/qwiklabs-gcp-gcpd-502b5f86f641/r/default # timeout=10
>     Fetching origin...
>     Fetching upstream changes from origin
>      > git --version # timeout=10
>      > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
>     using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials qwiklabs-gcp-gcpd-502b5f86f641
>      > git fetch --tags --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>     Seen branch in repository origin/master
>     Seen branch in repository origin/new-feature
>     Seen 2 remote branches
>     Obtained Jenkinsfile from 4bbac0573482034d73cee17fa3de8999b9d47ced
>     Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
>     [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
>     [Pipeline] podTemplate
>     [Pipeline] {
>     [Pipeline] node
>     Still waiting to schedule task
>     Waiting for next available executor
>     Agent sample-app-f7hdx-n3wfx is provisioned from template Kubernetes Pod Template
>     ---
>     apiVersion: "v1"
>     kind: "Pod"
>     metadata:
>       annotations:
>         buildUrl: "http://cd-jenkins:8080/job/sample-app/job/new-feature/1/"
>       labels:
>         jenkins: "slave"
>         jenkins/sample-app: "true"
>       name: "sample-app-f7hdx-n3wfx"
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - command:
>         - "cat"
>         image: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl"
>         name: "kubectl"
>         tty: true
>         volumeMounts:
>         - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
>           name: "workspace-volume"
>           readOnly: false
>       - command:
>         - "cat"
>         image: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
>         name: "gcloud"
>         tty: true
>         volumeMounts:
>         - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
>           name: "workspace-volume"
>           readOnly: false
>       - command:
>         - "cat"
>         image: "golang:1.10"
>         name: "golang"
>         tty: true
>         volumeMounts:
>         - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
>           name: "workspace-volume"
>           readOnly: false
>       - env:
>         - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
>           value: "********"
>         - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
>           value: "cd-jenkins-agent:50000"
>         - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
>           value: "sample-app-f7hdx-n3wfx"
>         - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
>           value: "sample-app-f7hdx-n3wfx"
>         - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
>           value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
>         - name: "JENKINS_URL"
>           value: "http://cd-jenkins:8080/"
>         image: "jenkins/jnlp-slave:alpine"
>         name: "jnlp"
>         volumeMounts:
>         - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
>           name: "workspace-volume"
>           readOnly: false
>       nodeSelector: {}
>       restartPolicy: "Never"
>       serviceAccountName: "cd-jenkins"
>       volumes:
>       - emptyDir: {}
>         name: "workspace-volume"
>
>     Running on sample-app-f7hdx-n3wfx in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/sample-app_new-feature
>     [Pipeline] {
>     [Pipeline] stage
>     [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
>     [Pipeline] checkout
>     [Pipeline] }
>     [Pipeline] // stage
>     [Pipeline] }
>     [Pipeline] // node
>     [Pipeline] }
>     [Pipeline] // podTemplate
>     [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Jenkins.instance is missing. Read the documentation of Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull to see what you are
> doing wrong.
>       at jenkins.model.Jenkins.get(Jenkins.java:772)
>       at hudson.model.Hudson.getInstance(Hudson.java:77)
>       at com.google.jenkins.plugins.source.GoogleRobotUsernamePassword.areOnMaster(GoogleRobotUsernamePassword.java:146)
>       at com.google.jenkins.plugins.source.GoogleRobotUsernamePassword.readObject(GoogleRobotUsernamePassword.java:180)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1975)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:290)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:189)
>     Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 10.8.2.12/10.8.2.12:53086
>           at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1743)
>           at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
>           at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:957)
>           at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:283)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.addCredentials(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl.addCredentials(RemoteGitImpl.java:200)
>           at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:845)
>           at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:813)
>           at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:124)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     Caused: java.lang.Error: Failed to deserialize the Callable object.
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:195)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
>       at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
>       at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:97)
>     Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from 10.8.2.12/10.8.2.12:53086 failed
>       at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:963)
>       at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:283)
>     Caused: hudson.remoting.RemotingSystemException
>       at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:299)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.addCredentials(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl.addCredentials(RemoteGitImpl.java:200)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:845)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:813)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:124)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>     Finished: FAILURE
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed. Please update the Google Authenticated Source Plugin to version 0.4.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-source-plugin/pull/9

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue as well ... when running the quick lab.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-kubernetes-engine

For my situation, I suspect for some reason, the credential for "Kubernetes Service account" seems not shown up, and when I try to add one, it give global credentials with name "secret-text" ... not sure if it is the root cause, do you encounter the same situation ?

p.s. I am running on my GKE cluster, not qwiklab.